# Why does a match statement without a trailing semicolon cause an error?

Tags: rust

I have this Rust code:

```
use std::fmt;

struct S {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: Vec<String>,
}

impl fmt::Display for S {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        match &self.a {
            -1 => {
                if &self.b < &0 {
                    write!(f, "Invalid a & b\n")
                } else {
                    write!(f, "Invalid a, valid b\n")
                }
            }
            _ => write!(f, "Valid a & b\n"),
        };
        // not including this above semicolon causes an error

        if &self.c.len() > &0 {
            write!(f, "{}", &self.c.join("\n"))
        } else {
            write!(f, "")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S {
        a: 0,
        b: 0,
        c: vec![String::from("something")],
    };
    println!("{}", s)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1430af27c8277a46d7e3eb7fe3b3cca)

The match is there to check whether arguments `a` and `b` are valid, and the if statement below is to check whether argument `c` has at least 1 string in it to print out.

This code fails when I don't include a semicolon just after the match statement:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:14:21
   |
13 | /                 if &self.b < &0 {
14 | |                     write!(f, "Invalid a & b\n")
   | |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `std::result::Result`
15 | |                 } else {
16 | |                     write!(f, "Invalid a, valid b\n")
17 | |                 }
   | |_________________- expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
help: try adding a semicolon
   |
2  | ($ dst . write_fmt ($ crate :: format_args ! ($ ($ arg) *));)
   |                                                            ^
help: consider using a semicolon here
   |
17 |                 };
   |                  ^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
13 | /                 if &self.b < &0 {
14 | |                     write!(f, "Invalid a & b\n")
15 | |                 } else {
16 | |                     write!(f, "Invalid a, valid b\n")
   | |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found enum `std::result::Result`
17 | |                 }
   | |_________________- expected this to be `()`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
help: try adding a semicolon
   |
2  | ($ dst . write_fmt ($ crate :: format_args ! ($ ($ arg) *));)
   |                                                            ^
help: consider using a semicolon here
   |
17 |                 };
   |                  ^
```

I am trying to make sense of what this error means. I know that semicolons are used to discard the result of an expression, and it seems by putting a semicolon after a match I am discarding the result of the match expression. Looking at the error message it says that it expected a `()` type instead of the type `std::fmt::Result` on the lines where a `write!` is performed.

1. Why does it expect this `()` type, when all branches of the match statement and its inner if are calling `write!` and returning a `std::fmt::Result`?
2. When I don't include the second part of the code that checks the length of the argument `c`, suddenly the code works even without the semicolon. Why does it not error out without a semicolon when the second if that checks for `c.len() > 0` is omitted?

Comment: So what should happen with the result of `match`?

Comment: *When I don't include the second part of the code* — in that case you are returning the `Result` that the `match` evaluates to from the `fmt` function, the same as your original `if`/`else` does.

Comment: The right solution here is to add a question mark operator to each of the `write!()` invocations in the `match` statement. This will propagate any errors encountered, and you also won't need the semicolon after the `match` expression anymore, since it now has type `()`.